# Is there a way to download packages from nuget.org then do an offline installation into Visual Studio?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

My visual studio is installed on a machine which doesn't have internet connection so I can't download and install packages from NuGet Manager in VS.
So I am looking for a way to use another machine which has internet connection to download packages and then install on VS.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

1. First, download the `.nupkg` file:

   - Follow the instructions at [How to download a Nuget package without nuget.exe or Visual Studio extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894864/how-to-download-a-nuget-package-without-nuget-exe-or-visual-studio-extension)
   - Or use my Google Chrome extension [NuTake](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nutake/ibhhbcaipjilldjkhhblhgdedjgoecap?hl=en)
2. Secondly, install the `.nupkg` file into your project

   - Follow instructions at [How to install a Nuget Package .nupkg file locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240029/how-to-install-a-nuget-package-nupkg-file-locally)

Comment: does nutake only work on nuget.org? I need to do the same thing on VSTS

Comment: @doodlleus From the description of the plugin: "Add 'download zip' links to package pages on the Nuget.org website." Based on that, I would assume it only works on NuGet.org

Answer (score 10):

You can use the NuGet Package Explorer to download packages outside VS.

- https://npe.codeplex.com/
- https://npe.codeplex.com/releases/
- https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to proposed answers, you can:

1. Build solution to restore packages (online).
2. Refer to the packages folder in your `NuGet.config`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="Offline packages" value="offline-packages" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

**NOTE that:**

1. `NuGet.config` should be in the same directory as your solution (`*.sln`) file.
2. If you want to push packages to the repository, rename directory or remove `**/packages/*` from the `.gitignore`.
3. In the above example, packages are moved to the `offline-packages` directory.