# How to install new assemblies from NuGet packages in offline mode

Tags: c#, wpf, nuget-package

I do not have access to Internet for couple of hours and I need to start a project using VS 2015 community version.

- Newtonsoft.Json
- Esri.ArcGISRuntime.WPF

I already have theses two assemblies on previous projects. How can I use those existing assemblies on my new project? Or is there any way to add them to my new project in offline mode?

Comment: you can add new source to NuGet Package manager to local source.in visual studio: Tools>Options>Nuget Package Manager>Package Source

Comment: Why do you need Nuget when you got them already in your machine locally? You can go to the properties of those two assemblies in Visual Studio and navigate to their physical path, copy them and add them to your project's bin/debug folder. Then just add the references and build.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to download packages from nuget.org then do an offline installation into Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120289/is-there-a-way-to-download-packages-from-nuget-org-then-do-an-offline-installati)