# Can you send A nuget as a package/zip?

Tags: .net, nuget

Hi I got an environment where Nuget is closed(cant use Nuget or download new packages), so I thought about downloading the Nuget package  on my other computer and just mail it over to the other computer. So I was wondering how I could do this. zip package --> email --> open in new environment ass a DLL.

Comment: A nuget package is a zip file already so you can rename it and send it and then rename it back.

Comment: ah okey, do you know how/where i can extract it from ? how to get it over to my email

Comment: Build the same project locally and depending on how nuget is setup, you will find the packages under the "packages" folder in the solution directory or in the nuget cache of the current user.

Comment: Or create an empty project that references whatever nugets you want if that is quicker.

Comment: Windows: %userprofile%\.nuget\packages. ah found them at this directory

Comment: when i drop the nuget package in the package folder, it still cant use it. do i need to install it in some way with the cli ?

Comment: The project should already have a reference to it with a path to packages. If you open the csproj in a text editor, you should find where it is being looked for to make sure the path is correct.

Comment: in csproj the only xml code is  ' <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Humanizer.Core" Version="2.13.14" />
  </ItemGroup>' when i added my package manually in the csproj i came up as in solution explorer but still cant use it. no alternative is showing when i try to fetch it with "using"

Comment: Whatever environment you are on, you can set up and use your own NuGet feeds, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds Sometimes it can be a shared folder, or even a USB drive.

Comment: It's a duplicate. Here is a comprehensive answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120289/is-there-a-way-to-download-packages-from-nuget-org-then-do-an-offline-installati