# Can't Install Microsoft.EntityFramworkCore.Sqlserver

Tags: c#, nuget-package

I am using visual studio 2022 IDE and Despite several attempts I was not able to install the package `Microsoft.EntityFramworkCore.Sqlserver`.here are my settings[Package Sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TA84K.png)
[General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqwTM.png)

and here is the error message I get:

> The feed 'Nuget [https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json]' lists package 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.runtime.4.0.0' but multiple attempts to download the nupkg have failed. The feed is either invalid or required packages were removed while the current operation was in progress. Verify the package exists on the feed and try again.
> Unable to find package 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.runtime.4.0.0'.

The `optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer()` method does not work in my application because the mentioned package is not available

Comment: Have you tried a simple clear and rebuild to reset?

Comment: Yes if you mean Nuget cache

Comment: Could you please add your list of packages that you already downloaded? You can get it in your .csproj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the package from nuget.org and install it manually.
check out the link [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120289/is-there-a-way-to-download-packages-from-nuget-org-then-do-an-offline-installati)

Comment: Problem solved thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to install an older version.
Try with `5.0.8`

Comment: I have already tried but did not work unfortunatly